# HTML- Change color text after visited

Tags: html, css, colors, visited

I have the following piece of code where an icon and text are displayed

```
                  <div class="group-block last">
                    <a class="w-inline-block" href="news.html" data-load="1">
                      <div class="group-image bg3"><img src="images/coffee.png" align="middle"></div>
                      <div class="group-title">
                        <div class="title-text">Relaxar-te</div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

I want to change the color of the text "Relaxar-te" after visiting this section. That means, once I returned to this page, the color of the text changed. The CSS of "title-text" is

```
 .title-text {
   line-height: 68px;
  }
```

If tried to insert

```
 .title-text:visited {
    color: blue;
 }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I saw many forums where they are using this way, however, it doesn't work for me or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

`:visited` only works for links. So what you need is

```css
.title-text {
  line-height: 68px;
}

a.w-inline-block:visited .title-text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-block last">
  <a class="w-inline-block" href="news.html" data-load="1">
    <div class="group-image bg3"><img src="images/coffee.png" align="middle"></div>
    <div class="group-title">
      <div class="title-text">Relaxar-te</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It changes the text color, however, it is changed before accessing the option. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You mean, even before visiting the news page? In that case, are you sure you haven't visited the page, ever? Does it help to clear your browsing history? Or try this in another browser where you haven't visited it?

Answer (score 0):

You can target the text in this manner:

```css
a:visited .title-text{
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-block last">
  <a class="w-inline-block" href="news.html" data-load="1">
    <div class="group-image bg3"><img src="images/coffee.png" align="middle"></div>
    <div class="group-title">
      <div class="title-text">Relaxar-te</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It changes the text color, however, it is changed before accessing the option. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Ruser I'm not sure what you mean. Could you update your question with a snippet of what you are working with? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`:visisted` only works on the `a` tag. `.title-text` is pointed to a `div`

you could change your code like this to fix it:

```css
.custom-link:visited {
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-block last">
                    <a class="w-inline-block custom-link" href="news.html" data-load="1">
                      <div class="group-image bg3"><img src="images/coffee.png" align="middle"></div>
                      <div class="group-title">
                        <div class="title-text">Relaxar-te</div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

Comment: It changes the text color, however, it is changed before accessing the option. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Ruser could it be that you have already visited the link? maybe clearing history or changing the link will help to debug